vim how to hide the $ symbol permanently?
When inside vim, :set nolist works just fine, but I want this to persist. What's the right syntax to add to ~/.vimrc? set nolist doesn't work.
❯ vim --version
NVIM v0.7.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info

~
❯ 

Thanks in advance.

:verbose set nolist? to see where it was reset after being set in ~/.vimrc

You are talking about Vim but your output shows Neovim. Note that Neovim may skip your vimrc if it finds an init.lua. Please [edit] and provide a [mre] with the shortest configuration that exhibits the problem.
